# An extra attachement is being sent in php

Tags: php

I use the following code to create and send the csv file to a specific mail box in php. I can successfully receive the csv file, however, I do not understand why one more txt file called ATT00001.txt is attached also. Can anyone help me to take a look?

Here is the part of code for sending the mail:

```
// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on 
$to = "you@home.com"; 
$from = "me@home.com";  
$subject ="Test mail";  
$message = "please check the csv out!"; 
$headers = "From: $from"; 

$fileName = pathtocsv;

// boundary  
$semi_rand = md5(time());  
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  

// headers for attachment  
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";  

// multipart boundary  
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";  
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 

// preparing attachments 
$file = fopen($fileName,"rb"); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileName)); 
fclose($file); 
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"record.csv\"\n" .  
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"test.csv\"\n" .  
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

[image: One more text file is sent]

And when I view it, it is just an empty txt file. I open the mail in Outlook.

Comment: This happens when sending a photo from an iphone and viewing the email in Outlook

Comment: I have added a screen capture, hope it can make my question much clear. It is an empty txt file, but I have no idea why it is being attached.

Comment: @Cole Johnson, seems you have met similar problem before, so may I ask is this issue solvable?

Comment: Its metadata I think, like the resource fork on Macintosh.

Comment: @Dagon, ya, it has a size, so it should not be empty, but when I open it, I see nothing at all, so I am confused now.

Comment: You aren't terminating the last boundary correctly.  The line `$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";` needs to be `$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";` (note the extra `--` on the end).  See if adding that makes the empty attachment go awy.

Comment: so it is not possible to hide it from the mail, right?

Comment: @drew010, thank you, it works, may I ask why it is necessary to add an extra - at the end? Because in other lines, I also do not add it.

Comment: See also the second post [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/1047cf36-fb42-4a1f-b6de-442b38c09de5) by James-Luo.  That is most likely your issue, you are putting the attachment before the message body (actually you don't have a message body).

Comment: I'll make and answer and explain why.

Comment: Why do you say I dont have a message body in my mail, isn't the multipart/mixed type content a message body and the attachment is included as part of the message body?

Comment: That there is a standard MIME message which ancient email clients would display because they don't understand MIME, but it appears you don't have a message body (either `text/html` or `text/plain`) where the actual message content should go.

Comment: So is it because the whole message is in multipart/mixed type, so in the software view, it treats my mail as no message body? Since I should have added a text/plain type message before the attachment.

Comment: Correct, there were two issues, primarily that there was no "last boundary" and possibly that you added an attachment before a message body (text or html).  I'd recommend adding an additional body part before the attachment of type `text/plain`.  It can be left empty, or you could just say something as simple as, there is a message attached.  Also note I just updated the answer.  The original RFC I referenced was obseleted by the current one in the answer but in regards to this issue, they both say pretty much the same thing in slightly different wording.

Comment: May I ask how can I insert an empty body before the mime message? Is it a correct way to do so by setting $message = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n"."\n\n" at the beginning? And I also want to ask, if I add this empty body, will it affect the message show, I mean originally, the message show is the first part of mime body, but if I add a empty body before mime body, then which body in text/plain type is the message body?

Comment: @user1502740 You're correct, just add another section like that.  The email client will be smart enough to realise that the text part is the message and display that.  Hint: Find out how to view message source in your email client (gmail supports it too), and you can view the full body of email messages in your inbox.  I often find it helpful to look at legit messages sent by Gmail and Outlook clients to see how they construct the messages.

Comment: My problem was that I head the ending boundary as well as the "normal" boundary that produced the same error. So make sure after **each** attachement is the "normal" boundary and after the last one is **only** the last boundary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing the last boundary line:

```
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

to:

```
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Note the extra `--` at the end.

[RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) <sup>( § 5.1.1 - Common Syntax [page 19])</sup> states that:

> The boundary delimiter line following the last body part is a
>   distinguished delimiter that indicates that no further body parts
>   will follow.  Such a delimiter line is identical to the previous
>   delimiter lines, with the addition of two more hyphens after the
>   boundary parameter value.
>
> --gc0pJq0M:08jU534c0p--

Since the last boundary was missing, it seems to be the default behaviour that Outlook creates an attachment containing some extra data or an empty attachment.

The second answer [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/1047cf36-fb42-4a1f-b6de-442b38c09de5) by James-Luo may also be valid.  He states that adding an attachment to a MIME message *prior* to the message body can result in similar outcome with the attachments.

Comment: Good spot. Here's the MS KB artice on it - http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;969854 (but I couldn't see the errors)